# ¿Cómo muestro los datos traídos desde un servicio en los input de un formulario reactivo?

Tags: angular, typescript

En este caso dataPH solo trae el nombre, el cual lo quiero mostrar en el input nombres. (quiero realizar un editar).

```
// variable donde se guarda el nombre traído desde servicio

nombresValue!          : string;

// formulario inicializado ya que sirve para capturar información (este código no lo muestro pero sirve para capturar datos por eso lo inicializo vacío) 

  formInfoCotizante: FormGroup = this.fb.group ({

      nombres         : ['', [Validators.required]],
      apellidos       : ['', [Validators.required]],
      email           : ['', [Validators.required]],
      identificacion  : ['', [Validators.required]],
      fechaNacimiento : ['', [Validators.required]],
      fechaEntrada    : ['', [Validators.required]],
      fechaSalida     : ['', [Validators.required]],
      cantidadAdultos : ['', [Validators.required]],
      cantidadNiños   : ['', [Validators.required]],
      cantidadInfantes: ['', [Validators.required]],
      destino         : ['', [Validators.required]],
      observaciones   : ['', [Validators.required]]
  })
   
// el servicio se llama ServicioDatosPadreHijoService

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, 
              private _servicioDatos: ServicioDatosService, 
              private _servicioDatosPadreHijo: ServicioDatosPadreHijoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this._servicioDatosPadreHijo.disparadorDeDatosPadreHijo.subscribe(dataPH => {
      console.log('data1', dataPH);
      
      this.nombresValue = dataPH.dataPH;

      // desde la consola me muestra el nombre traído desde el servicio

      console.log(this.nombresValue);

      // se supone que debería cambiar el valor por el valor nombre traido del servicio pero no lo
      // hace el formulario se muestra vacío y la variable nombre toma el valor undefined.

      this.formInfoCotizante.patchValue({ nombres: this.nombresValue })
    })
  }
```

Este es el servicio

```
@Injectable({

  providedIn: 'root'

})

export class ServicioDatosPadreHijoService {

@Output() disparadorDeDatosPadreHijo: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es más fácil si creas un inicializador del formulario:

```js
crearFormulario(datos:Partial<MiTipoDeDato>){

  this.formInfoCotizante= this.fb.group ({

      nombres: [datos.nombres, [Validators.required]],
      ... las demas operaciones
  })

}
```

Con esto, cuando tu servicio este listo llamas asi:

```js
  this._servicioDatosPadreHijo.disparadorDeDatosPadreHijo.subscribe(dataPH => {
      console.log('data1', dataPH);
      
      this.nombresValue = dataPH.dataPH;

      // desde la consola me muestra el nombre traído desde el servicio

      console.log(this.nombresValue);

      // se supone que debería cambiar el valor por el valor nombre traido del servicio pero no lo
      // hace el formulario se muestra vacío y la variable nombre toma el valor undefined.

      this.crearFormulario(dataPH)
```

La otra forma es campo por campo.

```js
this.formInfoCotizante.get('nombres').setValue(datos.nombres)
```

> ## Omitir el servicio del formBuilder
>
> Puedes dejar de usar el servicio `FormBuilder` y cambiarlo por sus inicializadores. Para los grupos `new FormGroup({})` y para los controles
> `new FormControl("Dato de inicializacion que siempre será string", [... VALIDACIONES ...])`. Aunque esto es cuestion de gustos.